# Is the current rating of the buck converter must match the dc load current?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, design, solar-energy

I am designing solar system for 1.2kw, 12vdc load and I want to insert a 48vdc to 12vdc converter between charge controller and load.what are the main things that I have to look at when I select this converter beside looking their voltage rating?

Comment: The current rating, and/or the power (wattage) rating.  This must be at least as high as the load.  More if you are driving motors.

Comment: What if the load is remote base station? is the rating of the the converter must be same as load rating current(1.2kw/12vdc=100A) ?

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't really matter whether the load is "remote" or not, except that 100A is a huge current to send to any load that isn't nearby.

Comment: Are you sure that your load is 1.2 kW at 12 volts? As you realize, this will require 100 amps, Are you aware of just how big your wires will need to be? In most cases, a 1.2 kW load will be configured so as to require a lower current. The potential for power loss in your wires is very high, and the wiring itself will be stiff and hard to install or move.

Comment: yes, it is given as 1.2kw ,12vdc load. But in order to reduce the Amphour of the battery i calculate and select  the PV, battery and charge controller with 48v so to connect to the 12v load i  search dc to dc converter 48v to 12v but i cant find with 100A and 1.2kw.